# Specified Provides version in rpm spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, specifications

**What happend:**
I'm now working on a linux side-by-side installation issue since rpm no longer support to install the 32-bit and 64-bit same name packages on a machine at the same time. So I need to change the name of the 32-bit package from xxx.i386.rpm to xxx-32bit.i386.rpm. For supporting the upgrade of this package, I should provide the old package name: xxx in the spec file.

**Problem:**
I've looked into the pages of rpm.org looking for whether we can specify the version which we provided in the spec file like:

Provides: xxx = 16.0

I've done some test and it seems to work. But I can't find any offical explanation.
Does anyone else know the properly behaviour if I specified the provides package version in the Provides.

Comment: "rpm no longer support to install the 32-bit and 64-bit same name packages on a machine at the same time" Where did you read this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You can have a test on a OpenSUSE 13.1

Comment: Or I can have a test on a distro I use, where multilib works just fine.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Pls ignore this since my main question wasn't this.

Comment: **I** am still curious why you are saying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm putting aside that multilib is still supported by RPM (and I'm puzzled why are you doing that). But when i focus on that spec problem.

You have it nearly correct. Just omit that percent sign. Correct is:

```
Provides: xxx = 16.0
```

Note that the "16.0" should be just version. While it technically can be version-release, this will make you trouble some time later.

And if you want to provide really clean upgrade path, you should put there Obsolete too. See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#renaming-or-replacing-existing-packages

Comment: Tks for ur reply, msuchy. Your link was helpful and wonderful. By yhe way, the issue I met will be happend in newly rpm version which may be used by RHEL 7 or OpenSUSE or CentOS. You could no longer install different versions of both bitnesses of the same package.